# How to delete all files except the ones with a specific pattern OR a specific type?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron, find

I have a script (executed periodically via cron) that downloads the latest version of WhatsApp from their server. I would like to retain just the latest version with the filename `WhatsApp_x.x.xx` in my server with a softlink `latest.apk`.

```
#!/bin/bash

 # Get the local version
oldVer=$(ls -v1 | grep -v latest | tail -n 1 | awk -F "_" '{print $2}' | grep -oP ".*(?=.apk)")

# Get the server version
newVer=$(wget -q -O - "$@" whatsapp.com/android | grep -oP '(?<=Version )([\d.]+)')

# Check if the server version is newer
newestVer=$(echo -e "$oldVer\n$newVer" | sort -n | tail -n 1)

#Download the newer versino
[ "$newVer" = "$newestVer" ] && [ "$oldVer" != "$newVer" ]  && wget -O WhatsApp_${newVer}_.apk http://www.whatsapp.com/android/current/WhatsApp.apk || echo "The newest version already downloaded"

#Delete all files that not is a new version
find  ! -name "*$newVer*"  ! -type d  -exec rm -f {} \;

# set the link to the latest
ln -sf $(ls -v1 | grep -v latest| tail -n1) latest.apk
```

This is how my `/var/www/APK` looks like:

```
/var/www/APK$ tree
.
├── latest.apk -> WhatsApp_2.12.96_.apk
├── script.sh
└── WhatsApp_2.12.96_.apk
```

But this command:

```
find  ! -name "*$newVer*"  ! -type d  -exec rm -f {} \;
```

It's also deleting the `script.sh` file. How can I modify the statement to not affect other files? I can't think of anything.

This is the cronjob, if that helps:

```
* * * * * sh /var/www/APK/script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

With find, you can chain together multiple conditions of the same type. This leaves you with a couple of options:

You could blacklist other specific files, like this:

```
find  ! -name "*$newVer*" ! -name 'script.sh' ! -type d  -delete
```

Or just whitelist the `.apk` extension:

```
find -name '*.apk' ! -name "*$newVer*" ! -type d  -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /var/www/APK -type f -name '*.apk' -print | 
sort -V | 
tail -n +2 | 
xargs echo rm
```

That finds the `.apk` files under the particular directory,
sorts them by *version* (may require GNU sort),
removes all but the newest version from the list,
and shows you which ones will be removed.

If you're satisfied it's finding the right files, take out `echo`

---

Taking a different approach: I'm going to assume that all the APK files are in the same directory, and that the filenames do not contain whitespace.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob nullglob
cd /var/www/APK
apk_files=( printf "%s\n" !(latest).apk | sort -V )
newest=${apk_files[0]}
for (( i=1; i < ${#apk_files[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo rm "${apk_files[i]}"
done
ln -f -s "$newest" latest.apk
```

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear; I actually want to remove all the versions EXCEPT the newest. And make a symlink to the newest one.

Comment: I mistyped. My code actually does "remove all but".